# Pasar orden de una lista a otra

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, tenemos una lista que está ordenada por un fitness ya calculado llamada 'puntuados'. Estamos intentando que 'poblacionNueva' conserve el orden de 'puntuados' pero que no aparezcan los valores fitness de cada elemento.

```
def selection_and_reproduction(poblacionNueva):


listaVistos = []
puntuados = [ [calcularFitness(i), i] for i in poblacionNueva] 
def takeSecond(puntuados):
    return puntuados[0]
puntuados = sorted(puntuados, key=takeSecond) 
print("NUEVA ITERACION:\n")
print("Puntuados:\n%s"%(puntuados))

selected =  puntuados[(len(puntuados)-indAReproducir):] 

for i in range(len(poblacionNueva)-indAReproducir):
    punto = random.randint(1,largo-1) 
    padre = random.sample(selected, 2) 

    while punto in listaVistos:
        punto = random.randint(1,largo-1)
    print("Punto:%s"%(punto))
    listaVistos.append(punto)


    print("Punto:%s"%(punto))
    print("Padre:%s"%(padre))
    poblacionNueva[i][:punto] = (padre[0])[1][:punto] #Se mezcla el material genetico de los padres en cada nuevo individuo
    print("Primera parte:%s"%(poblacionNueva[i][:punto]))

    poblacionNueva[i][punto:] = (padre[1])[1][punto:]
    print("Segunda parte:%s"%(poblacionNueva[i][punto:]))

    i = poblacionNueva[i][:punto] + poblacionNueva[i][punto:]

    print("Individuo Generado CON FITNESS:%s"%[calcularFitness(i),i])


    print("Poblacion Nueva FINAL:\n%s"%(poblacionNueva))

return poblacionNueva
```

EDIT 1: Generamos una poblacion inicial random. `puntuados`es una lista de listas donde cada lista esta formado por el valor fitness y un número de 5 cifras y además esta ordenada por el valor fitness. Se generan 4 individuos a partir de los padres (numeros con mayor valor fitness, en este caso 2). `PoblacionNueva`deberia ser una lista de listas donde las primeras 4 fuesen los 4 individuos generados y las dos ultimas los padres de la poblacion anterior.

Como se observa, ya en la primer individuo generado, el orden de `puntuados`se pierde en la primera Poblacion Nueva Final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te pediría que resumas la pregunta al mínimo fragmento de código que ilustre el problema (visita ["Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) si tienes dudas). Demasiado código a revisar para darte una respuesta simple. Con una versión resumida mostrarías que tienes bien enfocado el problema, además de poder darte mejores soluciones.

Comment: También, por favor, indenta correctamente el código. Sin indentar correctamente el código es complicado tener que adivinar lo que se pretende hacer.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Buenas, sinceramente creo que todo el código que he mostrado es necesario para poder hallar una solución a mi pregunta.

Comment: @kikocorreoso El codigo está bien indentado, ya que no da ningun error en la aplicación en la que estamos realizando el proyecto

Comment: después de la primera línea al menos una línea debería estar indentada sino dará error. Yo no veo nada dentro de la función `selection_and_reproduction`.

Comment: @kikocorreoso Nosotros utilizamos Jupyter como editor de código y nos ejecuta de manera correcta devolviendo el resultado esperado con el código que tenemos hecho, no dando error de indentar

Comment: @CarlosLozano Si tu problema es que quieres conservar el orden de una lista en otra, lo mínimo que deberíamos poder ver son las dos listas (sus valores) junto con el fragmento de código que transforma una en otra. Que sea necesario no quiere decir que nos sea de ayuda.

Comment: @ChemaCortes ya he puesto el fragmento donde se ven el valor de ambas listas.

Comment: Algo mejor, aunque hubieran estado bien tener las listas como texto o como código python para poder hacer pruebas sin tener que teclearlas nosotros a mano. Ojo también con la identación (la que vemos aquí, no la que ves en jupyter) y con reusar variables como `i`, que empleas como índice y como lista, o `puntuados`, que usas como item en la función `takeSecond` y como lista fuera.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Gracias por las indicaciones, lo tendré en cuenta la próxima vez. En un par de horas, miro tu respuesta. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El orden de la lista no es *"automático"*. Al alterar un individuo de la población, se alterará el orden que se tenía por `FITNESS`, siendo necesario volver a ordenar la lista. Lo adecuado sería volver a ordenar la lista al finalizar las mutaciones antes de retornar. Si no necesitas el *fitness* para nada, lo mejor es usar directamente la función `calculaFitness` para ordenar la población.

```
poblacion_nueva = sorted(poblacion, key=calculaFitness)
```

Desconozco algunas variables y funciones que usas. Las he dejado como *"globales"* con lo que tu código podría quedar algo así:

```
def selection_and_reproduction(poblacion):

    global largo
    global indAReproducir
    global calcularFitness

    num_mutantes = len(poblacion) - indAReproducir
    poblacion_nueva = sorted(poblacion, key=calcularFitness)

    # usamos como padres los que tienen más fitness
    padres =  poblacion_nueva[num_mutantes:] 

    listaVistos = []

    for i in range(num_mutantes ):

        (padre, madre) = random.sample(padres, 2) 

        # obtener un punto aleatorio que no se haya mirado ya
        punto = random.randint(1, largo-1) 
        while punto in listaVistos:
            punto = random.randint(1, largo-1)
        listaVistos.append(punto)

        print("Punto:", punto)
        print("Padres:", padre, madre)

        #Se mezcla el material genetico de los padres en cada nuevo individuo
        poblacion_nueva[i] = padre[0][1][:punto] + madre[1][1][punto:]

        individuo = poblacion_nueva[i]
        fitness = calcularFitness(individuo)
        print(f"Individuo Generado con FITNESS {fitness}: {individuo}")

    poblacion_nueva.sort(key=calcularFitness)
    print("Poblacion Nueva FINAL:\n%s"%(poblacion_nueva))

    return poblacion_nueva
```